# How to ignore nested node modules when running mocha?

Tags: regex, mocha.js, create-react-app

I have a project with the following setup:

Project

```
|- node_modules  
|- server  
|- client // nested create-react-app  
    |- node_modules  
    |- package.json
    |-etc
|- package.json
|- etc
```

From project root, I'd like to run mocha recursively throughout both `server` and `client` directories (or any other directory that may be required) looking to `*.test.js` files, while ignoring all `node_modules` directories.

[This article](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/02/07/mocha-glob-pattern/) explained how to run mocha recursively while ignoring `node_modules`, but it only ignores the top-level `node_modules`. Mocha fails when it encounters `./client/node_modules`.

Is it possible to modify this command to ignore *all* node_modules directories, not just in the project root?

```
"test:unit": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register \"./{,!(node_modules)/**}/*.test.js\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Decided to run tests on specific directories, like so:

`"test:unit": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register ./server/**/*.test.js \"./client/{,!(node_modules)/**}/*.test.js\""`